# What is the shortest way to select the first available port in a certain range using Bash?

Tags: bash

**Aim:** Select the first available port in a certain range. E.g., if port 600 is unavailable then the availability of port 601 will be checked.

**Attempt:** The following script works as expected but is too comprehensive in my opinion:

```
PORT=601; until [ $PORT -gt 610 ]; do
    if ! [[ `ss -nat | grep "*:$PORT\s"` ]]; then
        echo $PORT;
        exit 0;
    elif [ $PORT -eq 610 ]; then
        echo "no ports available";
        exit 1;
    fi;
    let PORT+=1;
done
```

**Expected answer:** The answer that provides the most concise script will be upvoted and accepted. Note that the script should still be able to comply to the aim.

Comment: @drewbenn script has been updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this.  Benefits from only calling `ss` a single time.

```
USED=$(ss -nat '( sport >= :601 and sport <= :610 )'|awk 'NR>1{print substr($4,3)}')
for PORT in {601..610}; do
 echo $USED | grep $PORT >/dev/null
 if [ $? != 0 ];then
  echo $PORT
  exit 0
 fi
done
echo no ports available
exit 1
```

Slightly shorter attempt:

```
USED=$(ss -nat '( sport >= :601 and sport <= :610 )'|awk 'NR>1{print substr($4,3)}')
for PORT in {601..610}; do
    [[ ! "$USED" =~ "$PORT" ]] && echo $PORT && exit 0
done
echo no ports available
exit 1
```

Comment: I don't think you should have quotes around "$PORT" in a regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
PORT=$(ss -nat | cut -b47- | sort -n |
awk 'BEGIN{p=601} $1+0>610{exit(1)} $1+0==p{p++} $1+0>p{print p;exit}') ||
echo "no ports available"
```

For info, this is the format of the output of my `ss -nat` produces. Hence the `cut -b47-` which cuts precisely at the column entitled *Port*.

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN     0      5                 127.0.0.1:9292                     *:*     
LISTEN     0      9                         *:21                       *:*     
LISTEN     0      10              192.168.1.2:53                       *:*     
LISTEN     0      128             192.168.1.2:8000                     *:*     
ESTAB      0      0                 127.0.0.1:8000             127.0.0.1:38587 
TIME-WAIT  0      0                 127.0.0.1:8000             127.0.0.1:38574 
LISTEN     0      16                      ::1:3493                    :::*     
LISTEN     0      128                      :::111                     :::*     
LISTEN     0      128                     ::1:631                     :::*
```

Comment: When the script is run it returns `no ports available`, while port 601 is available

Comment: @Utrecht we probably have slightly differing `ss` output formats. Try adjusting column 47 to something else. When I do `ss -nat | cut -b46-` for example on its own, I hit the ":" in the 4th field (labelled *Local Address:Port*). If you prefer you can replace the cut by `cut -d: -f2` (2nd field, ":" delimiter) but you wont get the inet6 ports.